# Box Blur exercise | CodeSignal

Tags: vb.net

I am currently studying to improve my coding skills and I have been stuck at this problem. Under you may find the question, the example and my code.

**Exercise:**
"The pixels in the input image are represented as integers. The algorithm distorts the input image in the following way: Every pixel x in the output image has a value equal to the average value of the pixel values from the 3 × 3 square that has its center at x, including x itself. All the pixels on the border of x are then removed.

Return the blurred image as an integer, with the fractions rounded down."

**Example:**
"For

```
image = [[1, 1, 1], 
         [1, 7, 1], 
         [1, 1, 1]]
```

the output should be `solution(image) = [[1]]`.

To get the value of the middle pixel in the input 3 × 3 square: (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 7 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1) = 15 / 9 = 1.66666 = 1. The border pixels are cropped from the final result.

For

```
image = [[7, 4, 0, 1], 
         [5, 6, 2, 2], 
         [6, 10, 7, 8], 
         [1, 4, 2, 0]]
```

the output should be

```
solution(image) = [[5, 4], 
                  [4, 4]]
```

There are four 3 × 3 squares in the input image, so there should be four integers in the blurred output. To get the first value: (7 + 4 + 0 + 5 + 6 + 2 + 6 + 10 + 7) = 47 / 9 = 5.2222 = 5. The other three integers are obtained the same way, then the surrounding integers are cropped from the final result."

**My incorrect answer (so far):**

```
Function solution(image As List(Of List(Of Integer))) As List(Of List(Of Integer)) 
    dim lin,col,l,c as Integer
    dim resp As new List(Of List(Of Integer))
    Dim Aux as new list(of integer)
    
    Aux.Add(0)
    
    For lin=0 to image.count-3
        resp.Add(Aux)
        For col=0 to image(lin).count-3
            If col>0 then
            resp(lin).Add(0)
            End If
            For l=0 to 2
                For c=0 to 2
                    resp(lin)(col)+=image(l+lin)(c+col)
                Next c
            Next l
            resp(lin)(col) = Fix(resp(lin)(col)/9)
        Next col
    Next lin
    
    Return resp
    
End Function
```

**Extra info:**
It went well for the tests where image = [[1,1,1],[1,7,1],[1,1,1]] or [[0,18,9],[27,9,0],[81,63,45]] or [[36,0,18,9],[27,54,9,0],[81,63,72,45]]. But failed the first time it had four lines, where  image = [[7,4,0,1],[5,6,2,2],[6,10,7,8],[1,4,2,0]].

I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

At the end my error was quite simple. Adding  the list "Aux" to my list of list i was making a bond between them. And everytime I add another item thru `resp(lin).Add(0)` I was also adding an item in "Aux" itself. When I used this "Aux" onde again to add a new list it already contained more than 1 element.

To solve it  found in another post of stackoverflow ([VB.NET: 2-dimensional list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976599/vb-net-2-dimensional-list-is-almost-1000x-slower-than-1-dimensional-list)) with the following line of code `arr2.Add(New List(Of Double))`.

Here goes the working code:

```
    Function solution(image As List(Of List(Of Integer))) As List(Of List(Of Integer)) 
    dim lin,col,l,c as Integer
    dim resp As new List(Of List(Of Integer))
        
    For lin = 0 to image.count-3
        resp.Add(New List(Of Integer))
        For col=0 to image(lin).count-3
            resp(lin).Add(0)
        Next col
    Next lin
    
    For lin=0 to image.count-3
        For col=0 to image(lin).count-3
            For l=0 to 2
                For c=0 to 2
                    resp(lin)(col)+=image(l+lin)(c+col)
                Next c
            Next l
            resp(lin)(col) = resp(lin)(col)\9
        Next col
    Next lin
    
    Return resp
    
End Function
```